# AngularJs $resource delete request with body

Tags: angularjs, httprequest, angularjs-resource

Hi I know this question was asked many time but I did not found an answer to it.

How do I send a call with AngularJs `$resource` delete method to Web that have a body? I was not able to do it. I've struggle a lot, I've found some resource that are saying that  you can do it. Bellow are the links I've found

[delete to be method with body](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/8567) 
[$resource obj.$delete sends the resource as the request body](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/4280) 
[`$resource` DELETE doesn't set the Request Body if provided](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/10128)

But I don't know how can I do the delete with body. Can you please give me some example?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

See here https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/3207
( Too long don't read: **DELETE** should not with body )

Comment: While this is technically the right answer, it does not provide enough context to ensure that it continues to be relevant.  Since this question was posted a year prior to the answer, the link and the brief description won't be useful to the original poster, and should therefore be written with extra care to express why the answer is relevant to others.